# Fortran (ifort), openmp only using half the threads

Tags: fortran, openmp, intel-fortran

My computer has an Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6248 CPU @ 2.50GHz   2.49 GHz  (2 processors). So in total it should have 40 cores / 80 threads.

I have a fortran code that uses OpenMP. When I open task manager it seems to use only 50% of the processing power. Is it because OpenMP cannot use all the 80 threads? Only the physical cores? Or is it because my computer has 2 processors (i.e. two Intel Gold 6248)?

Or am I compiling the code wrongly?

I compile it and run it via the command line, see compilation log:

```
Compiling with Intel® Fortran Compiler Classic 2021.4.0 [IA-32]...
ifort /nologo /O2 /I"C:\Program Files (x86)\RogueWave\imsl\fnl-2021.0.0\win100in212i32\include\dll" /Qopenmp /module:"Release\\" /object:"Release\\" /Fd"Release\vc160.pdb" /libs:dll /threads /c /F60000000 /Qlocation,link,"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x86" /Qm32 "D:\Dropbox\AnnuitizationPuzzle\z_Annuity_fortran\annuity_puzzle\annuity_puzzle\main.f90"
Linking...
Link /OUT:"Release\annuity_puzzle.exe" /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\RogueWave\imsl\fnl-2021.0.0\win100in212i32\lib" /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:"Release\annuity_puzzle.exe.intermediate.manifest" /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /IMPLIB:"D:\Dropbox\AnnuitizationPuzzle\z_Annuity_fortran\annuity_puzzle\annuity_puzzle\Release\annuity_puzzle.lib" -qm32 "Release\linspace.obj" "Release\random_stdnormal.obj" "Release\main.obj" "C:\Program Files (x86)\RogueWave\imsl\fnl-2021.0.0\win100in212i32\lib\imsl_dll.lib"
Embedding manifest...
mt.exe /nologo /outputresource:"D:\Dropbox\AnnuitizationPuzzle\z_Annuity_fortran\annuity_puzzle\annuity_puzzle\Release\annuity_puzzle.exe;#1" /manifest "Release\annuity_puzzle.exe.intermediate.manifest"

annuity_puzzle - 0 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

This is the only openmp instruction that I am giving:

```
CALL OMP_SET_NUM_THREADS(80)
do var= 1, n_var

 !$omp parallel do default(private) shared(shared variables here) 
end do 
 !$omp end parallel do
```

Comment: How do you execute the code? How do you set the OpenMP environment variables? How do you set the number of threads? Which operating system?

Comment: It could be due to a load balancing issue regarding the loop. Try with a `dynamic` schedule. Besides, this I remember that old GOMP version has a maxthread constant set to 64 in the code few years ago. I hope they have fixed this since.

Comment: Vladimir, I edited my question. Not sure if this answers all your queries.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Intel does not use GOMP.

Comment: I would not use `OMP_SET_NUM_THREADS`, it is really inflexible. Try playing with the environment variables like `OMP_PROC_BIND`, `OMP_PLACES` and so on. Report back if it changes anything.

Comment: I will try. Removing the OMP_SET_NUM_THREADS line has no impact whatsoever on performance.

Comment: Indeed, my bad for GOMP. A binding issue is likely to occur, especially on HPC clusters since job scheduler fix some affinity mask manually. `KMP_AFFINITY=verbose` can be used to show the binding of threads. Note also that `OMP_DISPLAY_ENV` can help to find surprising bugs (like using two OpenMP runtime at the same time)

Comment: Of course it had no impact, it is just inflexible. The other options are to be tested.

Comment: Try `OMP_PLACES="threads"` and `OMP_PROC_BIND="true"`. Check the manual, it is possible I do not recall all the details correctly.

Comment: What does "50% of processing power" mean? I see no computations in your code so any indication of load should be very low.